# How do you change the name of the GoogleOauth2 omniauth provider name?

Tags: ruby, oauth, omniauth

I am using the Google Omniauth gem [here](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) and need to provide two instances of it so I can have them ask for a different set of permissions. I have this working with an equivalent Facebook gem using this [guide](https://www.cookieshq.co.uk/posts/how-to-create-multiple-facebook-omniauth-strategies-for-the-same-application/). Doing the same thing doesn't work with the Google gem. Does anyone know what I can do to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. For some reason, the Google Oauth2 gem doesn't work with the provider name as a symbol, but will take the class name. So I am able to solve this problem with this:

```
# initializers/omniauth.rb
module OmniAuth::Strategies
  class GoogleIntegration < GoogleOauth2
  end
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleIntegration, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    {
      ...
    }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years late, but here's now the proper way of doing it:

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleIntegration,
           ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
           ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
           name: 'google_integration' # <=== Use the name option.
end
```